# Javascript setTimeout issue w/ for loop

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, settimeout

This is my function, when called the related node turns red and then does nothing.

Here is the javascript:

```
function blink (node, flickers)
{
    originalColour = node.style.color;
    for (i = 1; i <= (flickers*2); i++)
        {
        setTimeout (function () {ChangeColor (node, (((i%2) == 0) ? (originalColour) : ('red')))}, (i*200));
        }
}
function ChangeColor (node, color) 
{
    node.style.color = color;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`i` is "`i` when the anonymous function is called" not "`i` when `setTimeout` is called".

You need to create a closure and pass the current value of `i` into it.

```
function ChangeColorLater(i) {
    return function () {
        ChangeColor (node, (((i%2) == 0) ? (originalColour) : ('red')))
    }
}

setTimeout (ChangeColourLater(i), (i*200));
```

Comment: I am really very sorry, is this what you mean:

function blink (node, flickers)
{
 alert('start');
 originalColour = node.style.color;
 for (i = 1; i <= (flickers*2); i++)
  {
  alert(i);
  setTimeout (ChangeColourLater(i, node), (i*200));
  }
}

function ChangeColorLater(i, node) 
{
 alert("2 " + i);
    return function () {
        ChangeColor (node, (((i%2) == 0) ? (originalColour) : ('red')))
    }
}

function ChangeColor (node, color) 
{
 node.style.color = color;
}

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what I am doing with stackoverflow - I can't get code tags to work in the comments - I will figure it out eventually

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that at the time each timeout executes, i is equal to flickers * 2.

Using a closure, you can capture the value of i when the timeout is set, and pass that to your ChangeColor function. At the time the callback is executed, index (below) will equal the value of i  at the time that the timeout was set.

What you want is:

```
function blink (node, flickers) {
    var originalColour = node.style.color;
    for (var i = 1; i <= (flickers*2); i++) {
        setTimeout (function (index) { // current value for i in loop becomes var index
            return function() {
                ChangeColor(node, (index % 2 == 0) ? originalColour : 'red');
            }
        }(i), i*200)
    }
}
function ChangeColor (node, color) {
    node.style.color = color;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit easier to read. http://jsfiddle.net/wUkfe/22/

```
function blink(node, flickers){

  var color = node.style.color;

  (function blinker(){

    node.style.color = (flickers % 2) ?  "red" : color;

    if (flickers--){
      setTimeout(blinker, 1000);
    }

  })();

}
```