# Timeout which overwrites data (JS)

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, timeout

I have a loop that calls a function thrice with different parameters using different timeout intervals:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myArray = [];

    for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
        myArray[i] = [];
        myArray[i]['second'] = (1+i)*3000;
        myArray[i]['valeur'] = i+i;

        setTimeout(function() {
            otherfunction(myArray[i]['valeur']);
        }, myArray[i]['second']);
    }

    function otherfunction(data1) {
        console.log(data1);
    }
</script>
```

The script correctly calls otherfunction() but there's an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'valeur' of undefined

how do I solve this problem. Looks like a problem concerning variable scope.

Comment: The JS array is not meant to be used with keys. What you want is a JSON object: `myArray[i] = {}`.

Comment: At which point the variable is probably misnamed...

Comment: You got yourself a closure looping problem. All the iterations are pointing to the same value. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567118/javascript-settimeout-issue-w-for-loop?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change it like:

```
for (i=0; i<3; i++)
{

    myArray[i] = new Array();
    myArray[i]['second'] = (1+i)*3000;
    myArray[i]['valeur'] = i+i;


    var timeoutCallback = (function(valeur){
        return function(){
            otherfunction(valeur);
        }
    })(myArray[i]['valeur']);

    setTimeout(timeoutCallback, myArray[i]['second']);


}
```

The point here is using `JavaScript closures` to keep the current value of a variable in a scope, for your callback like functions.

As you see we have 2 nested function here, first one creates a safe scope to keep your current value of `myArray[i]['valeur']`, which totally depends on variable `i`, which in your for loop doesn't have a fixed value.

For more information about check this question out, this has the most valuable answers ever:

[How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Answer (score 0):

That's because in the timeout functions the

```
i
```

variable is already 3, and your array length is 3 so myArray[3] is undefined. You need to make sure that the functions passed to setTimeout have a closure on the proper value.

This will work:

```
var myArray = new Array();

for (i=0; i<3; i++)
{

    myArray[i] = new Array();
    myArray[i]['second'] = (1+i)*3000;
    myArray[i]['valeur'] = i+i;



    (function(val){
        setTimeout(function() 
        {
            otherfunction(val);
        },myArray[i]['second']);
    })(myArray[i]['valeur']);
}


function otherfunction(data1)
{
    console.log(data1);
}
```

Comment: Your code logs `4` three times. Try to change it so it logs `0,2,4`.

Comment: You were right, sorry my mistake. I edited it and the current version works as expected.